# Recode sqlite column values using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, rsqlite

I have an excessively big data saved as SQLite database. I need to recode the values of some of the columns but unfortunately my code generate error that i really can't debug. Here is the code i'm using.

```
library(RSQLite) 
library(inborutils)
library(dplyr)
library(dbplyr)
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), dbname = "ukbb.sqlite")
dbListTables(db)
bd <- tbl(db, "Uk_Bb")
bd %>%
  mutate(f.19.0.0 = recode(bd, f.19.0.0, '1' = "Direct entry",
                        '2' = "Manual entry",
                        '3' = "Not performed",
                        '6' = "Not performed - equipment failure",
                        '7' = "Not performed - other reason", 
                        .default = NULL))
```

f.19.0.0 is a column in the table and has those values: -

```
bd %>% select(f.19.0.0)
# Source:   lazy query [?? x 1]
# Database: sqlite 3.36.0 [C:\Users\*****\Downloads\UkBB\ukbb.sqlite]
f.19.0.0
       <dbl>
1        1
2        1
3        1
4       NA
5        1
6       NA
7       NA
8        1
9        1
10        1
# ... with more rows
```

The error i'm getting is

> Error in UseMethod("escape") :
> no applicable method for 'escape' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_SQLiteConnection', 'tbl_dbi', 'tbl_sql', 'tbl_lazy', 'tbl')"
> In addition: Warning message:
> Named arguments ignored for SQL recode

Any help/explanation to solve this problem is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand about your error, your code is not being translated back into SQL properly by `::dbplyr()`, I'm not sure this will work but I have attempted to provide the mutate function a more SQL like alternative to `recode()`, `case_when()`. Give this a crack and see how you go:

```
library(tidyverse)
bd %>% 
   mutate(
      f.19.0.0 = 
         case_when(
            f.19.0.0 == 1 ~ "Direct entry",
            f.19.0.0 == 2 ~ "Manual entry",
            f.19.0.0 == 3 ~ "Not performed",
            f.19.0.0 == 6 ~ "Not performed - equipment failure",
            f.19.0.0 == 7 ~  "Not performed - other reason",
            TRUE ~ NA_character_
         )
   )
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!